# Disc quota exceeded, cannot create, copy, or move files... is there another way?

Tags: filesystems, cp, mv, storage, quota

I'm `ssh`ing into a remote server to complete some work. I tried to edit a file in `nano`, but realized, after saving and exiting, the file (quite a lot of work) was empty. Apparently, my disc quota has been exceeded. I've deleted quite a few files (as in, all that remains are maybe 10 or 15 small text files), using `rm`, and I still get the error. I've never had this trouble before.

What I really need to do is access the data in a couple of those files. I tried using `mv` and `cp` to move the files needed to the folder for my public html page, but apparently I cannot do that, either (which I suppose makes sense in retrospect). Is there another way to move these files into the `/public_html` directory? By request, that's the only way I can get files off the machine and onto another. I'm in a bit of a pinch, so I'm really only concerned with getting ahold of that data so I can at least move it to another machine and work, as opposed to trying to diagnose the error itself just yet.

Comment: There is so much missing here.  Such as what are the permissions on your remote folder and files?  Is the remote directory local or network mounted?  What is the filesystem ulimit and what is the current number of open files?  It could be a failing disk (check the syslogs).  If you don’t know how or don’t have access to determine this, then it is best to reach out to the admin like @resiliware suggested.

Comment: @SteveO You're right, sorry. Unfortunately, I don't have the permissions to determine any of this, and the admins will be unavailable for some time.

Comment: No need to apologize.  Too bad the admins are so unresponsive

Answer (score 1):

`scp` the files on the remote machine to your local machine.

Something like `scp user@remote:/path/to/file localfile`

If for some reason you cannot use `scp`, I think you need to reach out to a sysadmin about why `mv` isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are *small*, and you do have a terminal, this is sure to work:

```
tar czf - file1 file2 file3 | gzip -9 | base64 | more
```

Copy and paste the base64 stream from the screen or (better!) the session log, then decode with `base64 -d`.

Another possibility, from outside, since SSH works (assuming `scp` does not):

```
ssh user@server "tar cf - file1 file2 file3 | gzip -9" > file.tar.gz
```

In both cases you now have a .tar.gz file on your server; "tar xzf file.tar.gz" will expand it to the original files.